# Select query selects only the first li element

Tags: jquery

This page have two ordered lists and I am trying to select eigth li element from both the lists. For that I use following query:

```
$('ol > li').eq(7).css('border-bottom','2px solid black');
```

But this query select the li from the first list. Why is it so?

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<body>
<br><h1>3.2 Reducing the Selection Set to a Specified Item</h1><br>
<h2>Eastern Conference</h2>
<ol id="east">
<li>Boston Bruins</li>
<li>Washington Capitals</li>
<li>New Jersey Devils</li>
<li>Pittsburgh Penguins</li>
<li>Philadelphia Flyers</li>
<li>Carolina Hurricanes</li>
<li>New York Rangers</li>
<li>Montreal Canadians</li>
<li>Florida Panthers</li>
</ol>
<h2>Western Conference</h2>
<ol id="west">
<li>San Jose Sharks</li>
<li>Detroit Red Wings</li>
<li>Vancouver Canucks</li>
<li>Chicago Blackhawks</li>
<li>Calgary Flames</li>
<li>St. Louis Blues</li>
<li>Columbus Blue Jackets</li>
<li>Anaheim Ducks</li>
<li>Minnesota Wid</li>
<li>Nashville Predators</li>
</ol>
<script src='jquery.js'></script>
<script>
$('ol > li').eq(7).css('border-bottom','2px solid black');
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `each()` function

```js
$('ol').each(function(){
 $(this).find("li").eq(7).css('border-bottom','2px solid black');
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<br><h1>3.2 Reducing the Selection Set to a Specified Item</h1><br>
<h2>Eastern Conference</h2>
<ol id="east">
<li>Boston Bruins</li>
<li>Washington Capitals</li>
<li>New Jersey Devils</li>
<li>Pittsburgh Penguins</li>
<li>Philadelphia Flyers</li>
<li>Carolina Hurricanes</li>
<li>New York Rangers</li>
<li>Montreal Canadians</li>
<li>Florida Panthers</li>
</ol>
<h2>Western Conference</h2>
<ol id="west">
<li>San Jose Sharks</li>
<li>Detroit Red Wings</li>
<li>Vancouver Canucks</li>
<li>Chicago Blackhawks</li>
<li>Calgary Flames</li>
<li>St. Louis Blues</li>
<li>Columbus Blue Jackets</li>
<li>Anaheim Ducks</li>
<li>Minnesota Wid</li>
<li>Nashville Predators</li>
</ol>
```

Comment: got a good eye on each() method now, great work. But the way i did was suppose to select all <ol> in the document, right!

Comment: Yes this method with each, select all ol of the document

Answer (score 0):

What your jquery does is it collects all the `<li>` from all the `<ol>` and then apply `.eq()` selector. So basically there is an array in which all `<li>`from all `<ol>` are present and from that the 7th is chosen. So it looks like it applies only to the `<li>` from first `<ol>` and not the subsequent ones.

@P.Frank's answer solves your query by making the use of `.each()` selector

Answer (score 0):

As explained in the [`.eq()` documentation](http://api.jquery.com/eq/):

> *Given a jQuery object that represents a set of DOM elements, the `.eq()` method constructs a new jQuery object from one element within that set. The supplied index identifies the position of this element in the set.*

So in your case, `$('ol > li')` first selects all li elements that are children of ol elements anywhere in the document, then `.eq(7)` selects the eighth one of those. `.eq()` doesn't know or care how the elements were originally selected or whether they have any relationship to each other. (If you had happened to have had three ol elements each with three li elements then `$('ol > li').eq(7)` would select the second li element of the third ol.)

One way to solve your problem is instead of `.eq()` use the [`:nth-child()` selector](http://api.jquery.com/nth-child-selector/), which *"[s]elects all elements that are the nth-child of their parent"*. Note that unlike `.eq()` the indices used by `:nth-child()` start at 1, not 0.

```
$('ol > li:nth-child(8)').css('border-bottom','2px solid black');
```

Expand and run the following snippet to see it working:

```js
$('ol > li:nth-child(8)').css('border-bottom','2px solid black');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<br><h1>3.2 Reducing the Selection Set to a Specified Item</h1><br>
<h2>Eastern Conference</h2>
<ol id="east">
<li>Boston Bruins</li>
<li>Washington Capitals</li>
<li>New Jersey Devils</li>
<li>Pittsburgh Penguins</li>
<li>Philadelphia Flyers</li>
<li>Carolina Hurricanes</li>
<li>New York Rangers</li>
<li>Montreal Canadians</li>
<li>Florida Panthers</li>
</ol>
<h2>Western Conference</h2>
<ol id="west">
<li>San Jose Sharks</li>
<li>Detroit Red Wings</li>
<li>Vancouver Canucks</li>
<li>Chicago Blackhawks</li>
<li>Calgary Flames</li>
<li>St. Louis Blues</li>
<li>Columbus Blue Jackets</li>
<li>Anaheim Ducks</li>
<li>Minnesota Wid</li>
<li>Nashville Predators</li>
</ol>
```